# If everything is a fairytale(vijnana bhairava tantra) then aren't all religious disputes just people arguing about which fairytale is better?

Tags: shiva, spirituality, consciousness, bhairava

Hare Krishna,
Recently while reading the english translation of **Vijnana Bhairava Tantra**, i came across a verse..
अप्रिद्धु मतीनाम एता िाऱविभीवषका्
मातृमोदकित्सिं प्रिृत्त्यथ धमदु ाहृतम १३ ॥
tr -
These things have been told (about the form of Bhairava),
like the tales used to frighten children, to induce people of
immature intellect to follow the spiritual path, just as the
mother entices her child with sweets.

Not only did this make me curious but there are several instances in the veda's and upanishads too that states that these things were just something like fairytales for the immature (us) to follow upon. Therefore, are all of these religions only stories that direct us towards the path of dharma? Are all of these religions—Islam, Christianity, Hinduism, Jainism, Buddhism—merely different flavours of god's fairy tales? I do believe that Hinduism is extraordinarily extensive, in-depth, and the greatest among them—just like a good fairytale. Please don't take offense—just my view.  just like a great fairytale. If god would've created earth then he wouldn't just choose a piece of land like South-east asia and gift this great religion to it, he would've created different flavours of it to suit different sects of people right? it might even be that these sects mispropogated their religions..and hinduism survivied these many generations the best.

It feels quite stupid that most of the conflicts in the world are just claims on which fairytale is better and superior? once this type of enlightenment reaches every layman, then I'm pretty sure all conflicts on religions will be solved completely and people will start living in harmony.

The bhairava tantra (the best book I've read so far) makes a clear and beautiful case for the best way to achieve bhairava, shiva's state, or enlightenment. It is so potent, and it is so enlightening that all of Lord Shiva's secrets are distilled into this amazing book of dialogue between Parvati Devi and Shiva.
I strongly advise everyone to read this book. You may obtain the pdf by just downloading it from the internet archive.

I am just a 14 yr old boy so if I have said something which you didn't like or is contradictory to your view then please apologize me and I would really encourage your views on this.

Thank You,
Nishant

Comment: 4 months.. and no reply ):